# Update mongoDB updating in forEach not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a Node backend server, connected to a MongoDB database. Here I have a patients collections containing patients object. I'm trying to update an attribute called position on each object.

I have started by retrieving the documents from MongoDB:

```
 const patientsToChange = await Patient.find()
```

Then I'm trying to update some attributes in the array by iteration over the array.

```
patientsToChange.forEach(function (patient) {
    patient.queuePosition = parseInt(patient.queuePosition) + 1
    console.log(patient._id)
    let updatedPatient = patient.update({ _id: patient._id }, patient)
})
```

What am I missing here?

Is it even possible to update in a forEach loop?

Comment: `let updatedPatient = PatientModel.updateOne({ _id: patient._id }, { patient: patient });` try this.
Just change the patient with model of patient.
And yeah it is possible to update in forEach loop.

Comment: shouldn't it be `Patient`.update({ _id: patient._id }, patient) ?

Answer (score 0):

instead of patient.update you should use Patient.update. Also it is better to use $inc for incrementing one field:

```
Patient.updateOne({ _id: patient._id }, { $inc: { queuePosition }} )
```